# Gcloud FileNotFound - ML Engine

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to do a predict on Google Cloud ML Engine. I have the input uploaded in a bucket at Google Cloud Storage. I'm using the following flag:

```
--file='gs://MyBucket/Photo/example3.jpg'
```

I've also tried:

```
--file=gs://MyBucket/Photo/example3.jpg
```

In my python app I'm opening the image in this way:

```
image = misc.imread(filename)
```

But the task produce the following error:

```
 "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://MyBucket/Photo/example3.jpg'"
```

I don't know if is a problem with the Google Cloud Storage permissions or the way I'm opening the image.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read image files from Google cloud storage, use tensorflow code like this, since native Python can not read from blob stores:

```
image_contents = tf.read_file(filename)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_contents, channels=3)
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32) # 0-1
```